# How to get only the MAX Value from Total for each stand_id

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I have table like this

[image]

that table is what i get from this query

```
select transaksi.stand_id,menu.nama_minuman, sum(detail_transaksi.qty) as Total from detail_transaksi
join menu ON menu.menu_id = detail_transaksi.menu_id
JOIN transaksi ON transaksi.transaksi_id = detail_transaksi.transaksi_id
GROUP BY transaksi.stand_id,menu.menu_id
```

the result i want is only the MAX value from Total for each stand_id

something like this

[image]

i hope someone could help me

Comment: menu(menu_id(PK),jenismenu_id,nama_minuman,harga)
transaksi(transaksi_id(PK),stand_id,employee_id,tanggal)
detail_transaksi(transaksi_id,menu_id,qty,harga,sub_total) this is the table structure

Comment: hm what about an subquery with something like "select sum(detail_transaksi.qty) as total" and in the main query you select the max from total?

Comment: It would be really easy if you would kindly provide ALL relevant tables with sample data so that we don't have to backtrack your query for table names. If you could even make an export and open the file in an editor so we could copy paste it into a workbench and have the exact same data without having to manually build the environment as well, that'd be the dream.

Comment: thankyou for trying to help but my problem already solved. i appreaciate it

Answer (score 1):

I'll try not to give you the complete solution, but let you figure it out yourself. Consider following code:

```
create table test (stand_id int, nama_minuman varchar(20), total int);

insert into test values (1, 'aaa', 2);
insert into test values (1, 'bbb', 3);
insert into test values (2, 'ccc', 1);

select *
from test 
where (stand_id, total) in (
    select stand_id, max(total) max_total 
    from test
    group by stand_id
);
```

NOTE: this is one of many ways to solve the issue.

NOTE 2: see what happens, when there are more than one max(total) per stand_id.